# Why CSS/JS files are being redirected from www to non-www domain

Tags: symfony, redirect, apache2

I have very strange issue (maybe it is known one) with file redirection form www to non-www. It is being done for css and js files. My website is http://www.toprandom.com/, for css and js files it makes request to www version then get status code 301 and redirects to non-www version. I tried to comment out each line of code in my **VirtualHost** as well as **.htaccess** but no result

**VirtualHost configuration**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName toprandom.com
    ServerAlias www.toprandom.com
    ServerAdmin support@toprandom.com
    Options All

    DocumentRoot /var/www/toprandom/web

   <Directory /var/www/toprandom/web>
            DirectoryIndex app.php
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride all
            Require all granted

    </Directory>

    RewriteEngine On
    ErrorLog /home/webs/logs/www.toprandom-error.log
    CustomLog /home/webs/logs/www.toprandom-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

**And .htaccess** is a part of symfony2

```
<IfDefine WWW_REDIRECT>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^stage\. [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfDefine>

ExpiresActive on
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 30 days"
ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 30 days"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 30 days"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 30 days"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 30 days"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 30 days"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 30 days"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 30 days"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 30 days"
ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff   "access plus 1 year"

; Insert filter
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE

; Netscape 4.x has some problems...
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html

; Netscape 4.06-4.08 have some more problems
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip

; MSIE masquerades as Netscape, but it is fine
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

; NOTE: Due to a bug in mod_setenvif up to Apache 2.0.48
; the above regex won't work. You can use the following
; workaround to get the desired effect:
BrowserMatch \bMSI[E] !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

; Don't compress images
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \
\.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary

; Use the front controller as index file. It serves as a fallback solution when
; every other rewrite/redirect fails (e.g. in an aliased environment without
; mod_rewrite). Additionally, this reduces the matching process for the
; start page (path "/") because otherwise Apache will apply the rewriting rules
; to each configured DirectoryIndex file (e.g. index.php, index.html, index.pl).
DirectoryIndex app.php

; By default, Apache does not evaluate symbolic links if you did not enable this
; feature in your server configuration. Uncomment the following line if you
; install assets as symlinks or if you experience problems related to symlinks
; when compiling LESS/Sass/CoffeScript assets.
; Options FollowSymlinks

; Disabling MultiViews prevents unwanted negotiation, e.g. "/app" should not resolve
; to the front controller "/app.php" but be rewritten to "/app.php/app".
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    ; Determine the RewriteBase automatically and set it as environment variable.
    ; If you are using Apache aliases to do mass virtual hosting or installed the
    ; project in a subdirectory, the base path will be prepended to allow proper
    ; resolution of the app.php file and to redirect to the correct URI. It will
    ; work in environments without path prefix as well, providing a safe, one-size
    ; fits all solution. But as you do not need it in this case, you can comment
    ; the following 2 lines to eliminate the overhead.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

    ; Sets the HTTP_AUTHORIZATION header removed by apache
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    ; Redirect to URI without front controller to prevent duplicate content
    ; (with and without `/app.php`). Only do this redirect on the initial
    ; rewrite by Apache and not on subsequent cycles. Otherwise we would get an
    ; endless redirect loop (request -> rewrite to front controller ->
    ; redirect -> request -> ...).
    ; So in case you get a "too many redirects" error or you always get redirected
    ; to the start page because your Apache does not expose the REDIRECT_STATUS
    ; environment variable, you have 2 choices:
    ; - disable this feature by commenting the following 2 lines or
    ; - use Apache >= 2.3.9 and replace all L flags by END flags and remove the
    ;   following RewriteCond (best solution)
    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^app\.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]

    ; If the requested filename exists, simply serve it.
    ; We only want to let Apache serve files and not directories.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule .? - [L]

    ; Rewrite all other queries to the front controller.
    RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        ; When mod_rewrite is not available, we instruct a temporary redirect of
        ; the start page to the front controller explicitly so that the website
        ; and the generated links can still be used.
        RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /app.php/
        ; RedirectTemp cannot be used instead
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Apache version is 2.4

Answer (score 0):

finally I found the problem. I have angularjs integrated to my project vie youman, so it has .htaccess which is redirecting.